# Programmatically read PDF embedded search index

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, pdf, indexing

The capability exists to embed a search index into PDFs using Acrobat pro (tools/document processing/manage embedded index) and other 3rd party programs such as Nuance.

I am writing an application for iPad users that will in part allow for pdf text searches with highlighting. There are a number of classes such as pdfkitten that do pdf searches. Some of the PDF files are large and take over 2 minutes to search using these classes.

I'd like to be able to access the embedded index directly to speed up search times. I've not been able to find information regarding the location of the index or it's format in the documentation I've read. I've looked at [Adobe's](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) documentation as well as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) and other ISO 32000 documents and have been unable to find out any information about the embedded index except how to create it.

I'd appreciate getting information that describes the index and how to access it or any classes that do. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found any information on that later? // @brian

Answer (score 0):

we were looking for the exact same thing.  Here is the blog from Adobe where I asked that question and Adobe's response was that custom page numbers and search indexes were not supported on the mobile Adobe Reader.  I'm looking for other options now for the iPad that will read and index searches effectively like can be done on desktop.

The blog: http://blogs.adobe.com/readermobile/2013/03/06/reader-mobile-update/#comment-2235

Hope the helps in some way.
-Brian